# If $A\subseteq(0,+\infty)$ is nonempty and closed under addition then it is not bounded above.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $A\subseteq(0,+\infty)$ be a nonempty set and closed under addition. Using the fact that the set of natural numbers is not bounded above, I can prove that $A$ is also not bounded above. I want to know that if is it possible to prove this without use of this fact? Thanks.

Comment: Since that property implies the unboundedness of the natural numbers, you can't prove it without some assertion that's essentially equivalent. What axioms for the real numbers do you have that might provide that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $A$ is bounded above.

Thus $A$ has a supremum $s=\sup A>0$

From the fundamental property of supremum we have that $\forall \epsilon>0$ exists $x \in A$ such that $x>s-\epsilon$

For $\epsilon=\frac{s}{2}>0$ exists $x \in A$ such that $x>\frac{s}{2}$

Also for $\epsilon=\frac{s}{5}>0$ exists $y \in A$ such that $y>\frac{4s}{5}$

Thus $x+y \in A$ and $x+y>s$ which is a contradiction

Comment: Wow, your proof is marvelous.Why couldn't I think of that?

Comment: I want to note that the unboundedness of the natural numbers is well hidden here, but it is used. Namely, to see that "fundamental property of supremum" (or to show that suprema with that property exist for bounded sets in $\Bbb{R}$) rigorously, one would make use either of that unboundedness directly, or of the equivalent fact that there are arbitrarily small *rational* $\epsilon >0$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg How about this? If $0<c<s$ then there is an $x\in A$ such that $x>c$. Since $s-c<s$, there is an $y\in A$ such that $y>s-c$. So, $x+y>c+(s-c)=s$ which is a contradiction. Would you think that I've used unboundedness of the natural numbers?

Comment: @user486600: Well, why is there such an $x$ and why is there such a $y$? (If you say that's part of the definition of supremum, then: why does every bounded subset of $\Bbb{R}$ have a supremum?)

Comment: To be more precise: If your definition of $\Bbb{R}$ *includes* that every subset bounded above has a supremum in $\Bbb{R}$, then this indeed entails the statement, as well as unboundedness of $\Bbb{N}$. (In a way, the "supremum axiom" combines completeness and the Archimedean axiom: It is a *stronger* statement than unboundedness of $\Bbb{N}$.) But if you define $\Bbb{R}$ e.g. as completion of $\Bbb{Q}$, then I'm quite sure you use what I wrote above both to define the completion, and then again when you show that in $\Bbb{R}$ defined like this, a bounded set has a supremum.

Comment: Also, think of it this way: The statement in your OP is true for $A\subset (0,\infty) \cap \Bbb{Q}$ as well. To show it there, you cannot use the stronger supremum axiom, but you can basically still adapt this proof by saying that, well, there might not be a least upper bound, but a bound within your set $+\epsilon$. But now you will need the fact that there are arbitrarily small $\epsilon >0$ in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg My definition of $\mathbb R$ includes that every subset bounded above has a supremum in $\mathbb R$. So this proof is indeed valid. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In order for  set to be bounded above you need to have an upper bound for the set.

Suppose A is bounded above and the upper bound is M.

Note that M is a positive number and  the sequence $(a_n)$ defined by $a_n=M/n$ approaches $0$

A is not empty, thus we can pick an element $a\in A$ and a large enough $n$ such that $M/n < a$

That implies $na>M$.

This is not possible due to the fact that $na = a+a+a+..+a$ is an element of A and it is larger than $M$ which is an upper bound  of  M.

Thus A is not bounded above.

Comment: But you've used the fact the set of natural numbers is not bounded above.

Comment: a is not necessarily a natural number but I agree with you that I am using the Euclidean Property of natural numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Pick any $a \in A$. Note that $a>0$. Since $A$ is closed under addition
an argument by induction shows that $na \in A$ for all $n=1,2,3,...$.

Hence for any $L>0$, if we pick $n > {L \over a}$ we have $na >L$, hence $A$ is not bounded above.

Comment: OK, But you've used the fact the set of natural numbers is not bounded above.

Comment: I have just used the fact that the set is closed under addition.

Comment: So how do you pick $n>\frac La$?

Comment: In any proof, the completeness axiom will appear in some form or other (existence of $\sup$, for example).

Comment: @copper.hat: Completeness is not needed, as the statement would still be true if one looked at $A\subset \Bbb{Q}\cap (0,\infty)$. What one needs is the Archimedean axiom, i.e. unboundedness of natural numbers.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg: You are correct, I was indirectly referring to the other answers use of $\sup$, etc.